# Is there any way to run an amd64/linux VM on Apple Silicon M?

Tags: go, apple-m1

I'm writing a program about transparent proxy with Go, but `syscall.SetsockoptInt(int(s), syscall.SOL_IP, syscall.IP_TRANSPARENT, 1)`is only supported on amd64/linux (Other versions don't have constant `syscall.SOL_IP` and `syscall.IP_TRANSPARENT`).

So even if I run a parallel VM (arm64/linux) on M1, I still could not build my program successfully. Is there any way to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what's the essense of the question. `IP_TRANSPARENT` is specific to Linux (an OS kernel), so any code which makes use of it *must* run on Linux. Debugging (a running process) also must happen on Linux—for, I hope, reasons now obvious.

But that does not affect building: when building on Linux, that should work *if* your version of Go has `IP_TRANSPARENT` defined in its `syscall` package.

This means:

- Running the program built for `linux/amd64` making use of `syscall.IP_TRANSPARENT` on the VM with a Linux guest should work.
- Building that program from the source code on the VM with a Linux guest should work.

But "plain" building on a non-native platform (which is `darwin/arm64` in our case, if I understand correctly) will not work, and this might be the source of your confusion.
Basically, when you're building the source code on `darwin/arm64`, the compiler *locates,* reads and interprets all the sources expecting to produce an executable image file suitable for the platform it's working on; the `syscall` package, being highly OS-dependent, can be though of as being different for different `GOOS/GOARCH` combos.
Its "version" for `darwin/arm64` simply cannot contain the symbol `IP_TRANSPARENT` because the darwin kernel does not "know" about it.

So, if your issue is merely building *for* `linux/amd64` while working *on* `darwin/arm64`, the answer is [cross-compilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_compiler).
With Go, it's done by making the toolchain see explicit settings for the `GOOS` and/or `GOARCH` environment variables—different from the assumed defaults.
In your case you could just do

```
$ GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build
```

and it will produce an executable image file ready for `linux/amd64`, and when processing the source code, the compiler will use the definitions for the target platform, not the platform it's running on.

You can then copy (or make availabe by other means) the produced executable image file to the guest's filesystem and run it there—it should work just fine.

You can make such changes "permanent" for the current Termial session by doing

```
$ export GOOS=linux
$ export GOARCH=amd64
```

---

**TL;DR**

- To build for a non-native platform, use cross-compiling; you do not need any sort of VM.
- Or you can build "natively" but then you need to install `go` into the guest running on a VM, and make the project's source code available there.
- To run an executable for a non-native system you must use a VM (or some sort of emulator).